# Overlapping Masonry with 100% height item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I'm trying to build a layout with a 100% height section - the twist is that this is a Masonry layout, and the first Masonry item is the 100% height/width of the page on load (& responsive).

Following the 100% height item, I want to have 'regular' masonry (columns, rows, etc. etc.)

The problem I'm having is that the first item `.grid-item grid-item--feature` is overlapping with the other items. I've had this before with ImagesLoaded, but never with an 'empty' grid.

I'm picking this back up after a month and probably overlooking something really simple but I've put together a [little JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/ezgbh38r/1/). How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
.grid-item-feature { position: relative; height: 100vh;}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezgbh38r/6/)

Explanation of the use of `vh` :

> With vw/vh, we can size elements to be relative to the size of the
>   viewport. The vw/vh units are interesting in that 1 unit reflects
>   1/100th the width of the viewport. To make an element the full height
>   of the viewport, for example, you'd set it to height:100vh.

Comment: Perfect, thanks +Vincent G. Does `vh` works within a nested `DIV` with a defined height too? 

For example, would it be possible to have a 100% vh div, which contains a 50% vh div? or would the second 50% div just be defined by a regular %?

Comment: I do indeed, perfect! Thanks